# Flutter>Hive: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart

in my app i want to detect in the splashscreen if this app is started for the first time.
For that i want to use the hive nosql package.

After that if the app is started for the first time it will open the welcome page and if not the login page.

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter_config/flutter_config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/splash/splash_page.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'config/theme/theme.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox('settings');
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  void dispose() async {
    Hive.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: lightThemeData(context),
      darkTheme: darkThemeData(context),
      home: const SplashPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

*splash_page.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/login/login_page.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/welcome/welchome_page.dart';
import 'package:app/services/settings_service.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashPage> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) =>
            Settings().isFirstTime ? const WelcomePage() : const LoginPage(),
      ),
    );

    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 125,
          height: 125,
          child: Icon(Icons.clear),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

there i call the function "*var _isFirstTime = Settings().isFirstTime;*" it should return me a bool

*settings_service.dart*

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class Settings {
  final Box _settingsStorage = Hive.box('settings');

  get isFirstTime {
    if (_settingsStorage.get('firstRun')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      _settingsStorage.put('firstRun', true);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

i got this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building SplashPage(dirty, state: _SplashPageState#261ae):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

how can i solve this? later i would like to use the settings service for other settings as well ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the setting_service.dart,
I think this line -> _settingsStorage.get('firstRun'), is returning null. From what I understand what you should do is that whenever you get firstRun as null, you should assign it true.

```
 if (_settingsStorage.get('firstRun') ?? true) {
      return _settingsStorage.get('firstRun') ?? true;
    }
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. I was pulling bool values but the value was absent hence return null. ?? false fixed it.